# Is there z score and t score formulas reference sheet for the different scenarios of hypothesis tests?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I've been working with hypothesis tests, and so far have come across several formulas for calculating z and t scores. One for comparing two sample proportions, one for comparing a sample proportion to a hypothetical population proportion, one for comparing a sample mean when the population standard deviation is known, one for when the standard deviation is unknown...
In searching the internet, I have not been able to find any reference or cheat sheet that shows all of these formulas with an indication of when to use each one. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!
(I'm very sorry if this post violates the forum rules. I'm yet to master all of the guidelines on this site.)

Answer (score 0):

I found one. Pretty sure this is exactly what I was looking for. Very helpful!
[image]